# android fromhtml cannot recognize all HTML tag

Tags: java, android

As far as I know, fromhtml of Android can recognize a few HTML tags like "`<b>`, `<i>`, `<u>`, `<a>`" and so on. But I cannot convince how to render following HTML code for android with fromhtml attribute.

```
String html = "<code style='background:#f0f0f0'>this is code</code><pre>this is pre</pre><table><tr><td>this is table</td></tr></table>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(html);
```

It's only for **TextView**, not for **WebView**. any solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I changed my mind to use WebView instead of TextView for displaying all HTML tag in android.

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, HTMLString, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: i too am feeling this is the only solution Android has provided. I am trying to use CSS with fromHtml and its seems to be not possible.

Answer (score 3):

Android doesn't support HTML in this way see [Html.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/text/Html.java) for supported tags. I'd extend TextView and parse/draw it myself.